# Why the copy constructor is called 25 times, while the insertion loop iterates only 10 times?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

I am wondering why in the following C++ code the copy constructor is called 25 times for 10 iterations?

If it was 10 then OK `10/10 = 1`, or `20/10 = 2`, or `30/10 = 3`, but `25/10 = 2.5`? What does the `.5` here mean?

**Header:**

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string name, int age);
    Person(const Person &person);

    const std::string &getName() const;
    int getAge() const;

private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
};
```

**Source:**

```
Person::Person(string name, int age) : name(std::move(name)), age(age)
{}

Person::Person(const Person &person)
{
    this->name = person.name;
    this->age = person.age;
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    cout << ">>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) " << count << endl;
}

const string &Person::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

int Person::getAge() const
{
    return age;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int main()
{
    vector<Person> persons;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        Person person(to_string(i + 1), i);
        persons.push_back(person);
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (Person &person : persons)
    {
        cout << "name = " << person.getName() << " age = " << person.getAge() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 1
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 2
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 3
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 4
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 5
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 6
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 7
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 8
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 9
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 10
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 11
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 12
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 13
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 14
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 15
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 16
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 17
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 18
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 19
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 20
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 21
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 22
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 23
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 24
>>Copy-Person::Person(Person &person) 25
-----------------------------------------------
name = 1 age = 0
name = 2 age = 1
name = 3 age = 2
name = 4 age = 3
name = 5 age = 4
name = 6 age = 5
name = 7 age = 6
name = 8 age = 7
name = 9 age = 8
name = 10 age = 9
```

Comment: That's reallocation. Probably from an implementation that doubles the capacity each time it reallocates. 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15.

Comment: The odd number comes from the internal memory re-allocation of the vector.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not reserving any memory for your `persons` vector. This means that when `persons.size() == persons.capacity()` during a `push_back`, the vector will allocate a new bigger buffer on the heap and copy every element to it. This is why you see more copies than expected.

If you write...

```
persons.reserve(10);
```

...before the loop, you will not see any "extra" copy.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WKS8z9OgbIjchExd)

---

Note that you can avoid the copies altogheter by using both `std::vector::emplace_back` and `std::vector::reserve`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    persons.emplace_back(to_string(i + 1), i);
}
```

This will only print:

> name = 1 age = 0
>
> name = 2 age = 1
>
> name = 3 age = 2
>
> name = 4 age = 3
>
> name = 5 age = 4
>
> name = 6 age = 5
>
> name = 7 age = 6
>
> name = 8 age = 7
>
> name = 9 age = 8
>
> name = 10 age = 9

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MoaEpussqJ1R6NbW)

Comment: is reallocation always a copy to a different memory location? or can it happen that there is some free memory just after that occupied by the elements, such that they dont need to be copied?

Comment: @tobi303: if that were the case then you wouldn't really have to reallocate...

Comment: errm right, my wording was off. Another try: Is it possible that the capacity increases without needing to reallocate? Btw for the `emplace_back` imho you should mention that it needs `reserve` plus `emplace_back`. Atm it could be misunderstood as `emplace_back` alone preventing all copies

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Hmmm.Thanks!  It makes sense. I have `reserve` + `emplace_back` no copy now. But one more question is it good that store the object itself to the vector or reference or pointer?  I am coming from Java, so in Java, you can directly store objects in the List, what about C++? Thanks Again!!

Comment: `vector` cannot do the equivalent of `realloc` and maybe keep the same starting address with greater extent: the allocator interface doesn't support it, and it wouldn't allow copy/move construction and destruction of the old instances to work correctly in the case where the start address _does_ move.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil: C++ is very different from Java. Do not use pointers and dynamic allocation unless you really have to. Prefer the stack and value semantics whenever possible.

Comment: @Useless: An implementation *could* provide a specialization for ``std::allocator`` and use some platform-specific extension to try growing the heap block. As you pointed out, ``realloc`` doesn't cut it for non-POD types.

Answer (score 2):

When the new `size()` > `capacity()` of the `vector`, reallocation happens. All the elements will be copied to the new internal storage, then the copy constructor will be called at the current elements' number of times. The details about how the capacity is increased depends on the implementation, it seems the implementation you're using just double the capacity for every reallocation. so

```
#iterator current size  capacity  times of the copy (for reallocatioin + for push_back)
1         0             0         0 + 1             
2         1             1         1 + 1             
3         2             2         2 + 1             
4         3             4         0 + 1             
5         4             4         4 + 1             
6         5             8         0 + 1             
7         6             8         0 + 1             
8         7             8         0 + 1             
9         8             8         8 + 1             
10        9             16        0 + 1
```

That's why you got the result of 25 times.

As @VittorioRomeo explained, you can use [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid reallocation.

Answer (score 2):

When `std::vector::size()` reaches [`std::vector::capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), `std::vector` will make room for more objects, allocating a *new* larger buffer with bigger capacity, and *copying* the previously stored objects into the new buffer.
This triggers new copy constructor calls for your `Person` class (I tried your code with VS2015, and I got 35 copy constructor calls).

Note that, if you reserve enough room in the `std::vector` with the `reserve()` method, you get exactly 10 copy constructor calls:

```
vector<Person> persons;

// Reserve room in the vector to store 10 persons
persons.reserve(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Person person(to_string(i + 1), i);
    persons.push_back(person);
}
```

That's because, in this case, you made enough room in the vector, so the vector's size doesn't exceed its capacity (so, there's no need to allocate a new larger buffer, and copying the old data to this new buffer).

All that being said, if your `Person` class is **move-constructible**, `std::vector` will *move* the previously created `Person` objects instead of copying them, which is faster.

If you add this line inside your `Person` class:

```
class Person 
{
  public:
   ...

   // Synthesize default move constructor
   Person(Person&&) = default;
   ...
};
```

you'll get exactly 10 copy constructor calls, even if you don't call the `vector::reserve()` method.

Comment: Yes, it was a good point that you have mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil: Thank you for your interesting question!